Combobox cell in DataGrid, Dropping down in one click instead of 2 - Possible?
I have a form that has a datagridview in it. I have bound this data with properties from a different class. The populating of the grid is working along with the populating from the dropdown is also working. The only question I have is it doesn't matter what I do I always have to click twice to get the dropdown to dropdown. Is there anything I can do differently to get the cell to dropdown on the first click? Any help would be appreciated.
Private Property MountingPadDGVinfo As New BindingList(Of MountingPadInfoForDataGridView)


Private Sub BulkMountingPadEditor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Populate Type ComboBox column with Enum values
        Dim padTypeColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns("Type"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        padTypeColumn.Items.Clear()
        padTypeColumn.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(MountingPadTypeEnum)))

        ' Populate Side ComboBox column with Enum values
        Dim padSideColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns("Side"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        padSideColumn.Items.Clear()
        padSideColumn.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(MountingPadSideEnum)))

        ' Populate Pad1Angle ComboBox column with Double values
        Dim pad1AngleColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns("Pad1Angle"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        pad1AngleColumn.Items.Clear()
        pad1AngleColumn.Items.AddRange(g_DefaultMountingPadAngles.Cast(Of Object).ToArray()) ' Ensuring it's casted to Object to prevent mismatch

        ' Populate Pad2Angle ComboBox column with Double values
        Dim pad2AngleColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns("Pad2Angle"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        pad2AngleColumn.Items.Clear()
        pad2AngleColumn.Items.AddRange(g_DefaultMountingPadAngles.Cast(Of Object).ToArray())

        ' Populate PipeDia ComboBox column with Double values
        Dim pipeDiaColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns("PipeDia"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        pipeDiaColumn.Items.Clear()
        pipeDiaColumn.Items.AddRange(g_PipeDia.Cast(Of Object).ToArray())

        ' Set the DataGridView edit mode to enter edit mode when a cell is selected
        DataGridView_MountingPads.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter


        ' Bind the DataGridView to the data source (BindingList)
        DataGridView_MountingPads.DataSource = MountingPadDGVinfo

End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDataGridViewMouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        ' Determine where the click is occurring
        Dim info As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = Me.DataGridView_MountingPads.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

        ' Check if the click occurred in a cell
        If info.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
            ' Set the clicked cell as the current cell
            Me.DataGridView_MountingPads.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView_MountingPads.Rows(info.RowIndex).Cells(info.ColumnIndex)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView_MountingPads_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_MountingPads.CellEnter
        ' Check if the entered cell belongs to a ComboBox column
        If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso TypeOf DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Then
            ' Begin editing immediately on cell enter
            DataGridView_MountingPads.BeginEdit(True)

            ' Get the editing control (should be a ComboBox)
            Dim comboBox = TryCast(DataGridView_MountingPads.EditingControl, ComboBox)
            If comboBox IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Make sure ComboBox is focused and force dropdown
                comboBox.DroppedDown = False ' Reset the dropdown state
                comboBox.Focus()             ' Ensure ComboBox has focus
                comboBox.DroppedDown = True   ' Force dropdown to open
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView_MountingPads_CellLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_MountingPads.CellLeave
        ' End editing when leaving the cell
        If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso TypeOf DataGridView_MountingPads.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Then
            DataGridView_MountingPads.EndEdit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView_MountingPads_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_MountingPads.EditingControlShowing
        ' Check if the control being shown is a ComboBox
        If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
            Dim comboBox As ComboBox = DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
            comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList ' Ensure it acts like a dropdown
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView_MountingPads_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_MountingPads.DataError
        ' Suppress data errors
        e.ThrowException = False
    End Sub

I have tried the above code and it is still requiring two clicks.
